# how to move turtlebot3 manually?(really stupid question)

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot3

What I mean by this is how do I move it exactly 1 meter forward or spin 3 radians around z axis (for example)? All the tutorials seem to talk about teleop, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question but manually is not the best word. Maybe a better way to formulate it is **How to develop a high-level motion planner for TurtleBot3?** The requirements are that it can plan tasks/commands like moving forward/backward 1 meter and rotating in place 1 radian.

Let's delve into the answer. To move the TurtleBot3 a precise distance or rotation, you must write a program that interacts with the robot's ROS topics, specifically `/cmd_vel` for velocity commands and `/odom` for odometry data, which tells us where the robot is and how much it moved.

Below is a simplified pseudo-code that outlines how to achieve controlled movement at a specified distance:

1. **Launch the simulated TurtleBot3 robot.**
2. **Implement a RobotController Class:** Its member variables and methods are as follows.
3. **Create velocity command publisher (member variable):**

   - Set up a publisher on the `/cmd_vel` topic. This will be used to send **Twist** messages to control the robot's linear and angular velocity.
4. **Create odometry data subscriber (member variable):**

   - Set up a subscriber on the `/odom` topic. This will receive `Odometry` messages, providing the robot's current position and orientation.
5. **Constructor:**

- Initialize the velocity publisher on `/cmd_vel`.
- Initialize the odometry subscriber on `/odom`. When new data arrives, this subscriber will call the below `odomCallback` method.

6. **odomCallback Method:**

- Input: Odometry data.
- Functionality: Update the current odometry information with the data received. Let's assume that the RobotController class has member variables that keep track of current odometry input so that we can process them in the next methods that move the robot.

7. **moveForward Method: (the logic you need for the forward motion)**

- Input: `distance` (the distance to move in meters), `speed` (the speed in meters per second).
- Functionality:

  - Record the start position (x, y) from the current odometry.
  - Enter a loop to keep the robot moving:

    - Calculate the current position (x, y) using callback updated odometry data.
    - Calculate the distance traveled from the start position.
    - If the traveled distance < `distance`, set the linear velocity to `speed` and the angular velocity to 0 in the **Twist** message, and publish it.
    - Else, or when the traveled distance >= `distance`, set the linear velocity to 0, the angular velocity to 0 in the **Twist** message, and publish the Twist. Then break the loop because the goal is reached.

8. **rotate Method:**

- Very similar in concept to moving, but tracks theta (orientation) instead of position. I would say get the moving done first, and it will guide you on implementing this.

This pseudo-code should get you started. It is not everything. For example, you still need to handle move backward commands. This means you need to be careful when tracking the sign and the direction. Just get the forward motion working and then implementing the backward motion will be easy. The in-place orientation also follows simply from there.

Comment: Robotawi: your answer is good, but it has so much detail that the "high-level" answer is lost. The shorter answer is: the OP has to create a ros node and repeatedly publish a Twist message to topic /cmd_vel in a loop. A message should be sent approximately every 200 milliseconds.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, @Mike973. I will consider that.

Answer (score 0):

The Turtlebot's default stack provides the `/cmd_vel` topic and an odometry topic (probably `/odom`). You can publish `Twist` messages until `/odom` reveals you've moved the appropriate distance, then publish a `Twist` message with all zeros to stop.

Here's a rough example in python:

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
import math

distance_moved = 0.0
initial_position = None

def odom_callback(msg):
    global distance_moved, initial_position

    # Retrieve current position
    x = msg.pose.pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose.pose.position.y

    if initial_position is None:
        initial_position = (x, y)
    else:
        # Calculate distance moved
        distance_moved = math.sqrt((x - initial_position[0])**2 + (y - initial_position[1])**2)

global distance_moved, initial_position

rospy.init_node('move_forward_node', anonymous=True)
rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, odom_callback)
pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
rate = rospy.Rate(10)  # 10 Hz

move_cmd = Twist()
move_cmd.linear.x = 0.2 # setting some linear movement speed

# moving forward one meter
while not rospy.is_shutdown() and distance_moved < 1.0: # using < not == because there's going to be some error
    pub.publish(move_cmd)
    rate.sleep()

# Stop the robot
move_cmd.linear.x = 0.0
pub.publish(move_cmd)
initial_position = None
```

I happen to have written a [ROS package for this](https://github.com/cst0/movement_utils) a while ago, but it's really just a more involved version of what you're seeing here.